# How to extract the range of value from a regular expression

Tags: python, pandas, regression

I  want to extract all alphabets(A-Za-z) and also any strings that starts with 9 e.g 9mobile, 9link etc from pandas series.

```
1000                          pos ba ganiyu fatai og ogng 9moble
1001                          99 ct justrite limited(ota) la lang
1002                          9link qt pymt airtime recharge 
1003                          qt pymt airtime recharge 56
```

9 should only occur zero or one time at the beginning of a string.

I came up with this regrex pattern `[^A-Za-z\(A9?)]` but it doesn't seems to extract what I really want.

I also tried this:

```
text = t.apply(lambda x: re.sub('[^A-Za-z\A9.?]+' , ' ', str(x)))
```

which resulted to an error

My expected output is:

```
    1000                          pos ba ganiyu fatai og ogng 9moble
    1001                          ct justrite limited(ota) la lang
    1002                          9link qt pymt airtime recharge 
    1003                          qt pymt airtime recharge
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to extract any string and anything that has a 9 as first character. In this case try this regex:

```
9{0,1}[a-zA-Z]+
```

So it should look something like this:

```
text = t.apply(lambda x: re.sub('9{0,1}[a-zA-Z]+' , ' ', str(x)))
```

Edit:

To remove only numbers from the list, use this:

```
\d+([^\w]|$)
```

So what this does, that it matches on any number that is not followed by a character or is followed by the end of the string, so it won't match on strings like '9link'.

Comment: I tried you solution, but it converts everything to a int. I want to retain all string and also any string that starts with `9`

Comment: Please extend your question with your fully expected output, because you wrote a whole different thing here than at the top.

Comment: Thank for your help, I just modified the code with the expected output, I also think that the caret `^` is missing on your answer

Comment: I edited my answer, please see it if that helps.